# отправка # (sharp) в чат телеграм ботом

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Имею простого телеграм бота, хочу реализовать отправку хештегов в телеграмм канал типа "#мойхештег" но когда строка начинается с #, то сообщение не отправляется.

```html
import requests
import misc

token = misc.token
URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/'

def send_message(chat_id, text):
    url = URL + 'sendmessage?chat_id={}&text={}'.format(chat_id, text)
    requests.get(url)

def main():
 send_message('-1001351502373', '#MyTeg')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Подскажите, как решить проблему? Спасибо!

Comment: Дело не в боте, а в том, что Вы используете ключевой символ. Закодируйте строку по всем правилам URL и только тогда отправляйте запрос

Comment: В дополнение к пред. комментатору https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-to-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python